# Cloud scalling and costs

Tags: cloud

First time I learned about clouds, I made suggestion, that when I create cloud VM there, I'll pay for the only resources I use. If I use 5% of CPU and 300mb memory I'll pay only for this and while getting higher number of requests it will temporary automaticly extend, which will cost a little more for me. But I found cloud providers is just a VPS sellers with pretty control panel. Are there any solutions exist in the world with pay-for-used-resources and autoscalling?

I don't request any concrete provider or tool, it is question about basic cloud architecture understanding.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it's asking for tool recommendations (vendor=tool in this case). Plus cloud providers have different pricing models for different services. unfortunately you accepted an answer that's inaccurate. Spend some time looking at the major cloud providers and how they offer their services and related pricing. **Cloud provider** does not equal **VPS reseller**.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I need no concrete cloud provider. I just wonder if described architecture has been implemented somewhere.

Comment: You set the premise, stating "cloud provider is just a VPS seller with pretty control panel." So, you're already starting with a false premise. And like I said: Spend a few moments looking at how cloud providers offer their services. You'll have all you need at that point.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Looks like language barrier or your distorted perception of pretty harmless question, may you change into constructive way?

Comment: Sigh. This isn't a discussion forum, and not the place to keep discussing this in comments (or throwing insults about my perception abilities). The question is off-topic: It's about pricing models. You can easily see what cloud providers offer. This isn't the place to talk about different vendors and their pricing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it is exactly as you wrote - cloud providers are only VPS resellers with some pretty stuff around it. It has  some advantage as IaaS providers like whole your infrastructure in one vlan, "unlimited" cloud storage, managed security, api for managing of resources and more, but nothing you cannot do with your VM by yourself.

You cannot pay only for really used resources or scale for little steps (as you can when you will build your own virtualization infrastructure).

Comment: Sorry but no: This is not a correct answer at all. Not sure why the OP accepted your answer, as it's simply not accurate in any way.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You may disclose `Cloud provider does not equal VPS reseller.` as answer here

Comment: @DavidMakogon ok, tell me what is wrong. Which cloud provider allows me pay only for resources really used and scalling cpu, ram and hdd separatelly (afaik I only scale everything, cannot make VM with small amount of CPU, large ram and large hdd)? If I have virtualization on my own hardware, there is no problem to setup VM with 1 CPU core, 32GB of RAM and 2TB of HDD.